# Facing this issue when initalizing sanity in vscode for my react app

Tags: reactjs, url, proxy, web-development-server, sanity

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-p    at makeError$1 (C:/Users/Shoaib/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/67a0730928194b24/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-f0037b46.js:1641:1417)
    at handlePromise (C:/Users/Shoaib/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/67a0730928194b24/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-f0037b46.js:1721:959)
    at async installDeclaredPackages (C:/Users/Shoaib/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/67a0730928194b24/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-f0037b46.js:1721:4682)
    at async initSanity (C:/Users/Shoaib/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/67a0730928194b24/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-f0037b46.js:17024:10577)
```

Making a backend for my Reat app via Sanity----------------------------------

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter persistent problems with the default npm registry, consider:

1. Using an alternative registry, such as npm's public registry. You can do this by executing the following command: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
2. Clearing the npm cache: Cached data can sometimes cause issues. Try clearing the npm cache by running the following command: `npm cache clean --force`
3. Upgrading npm: Ensure that you are using the latest version of npm by running: `npm install -g npm@latest`